# How to load file from the Internet into a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a method that compares the content of two files. How can I load an external url / Internet file?

One of the files is in my app and I load it using the line below, which seems to work.

```
file1 = File.open('app/assets/files/example.html')
```

But the second file is on the Internet. The line below to load the file fails (error: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`). How could I load the Internet file/page for my comparison method?

```
file2 = File.open('http://www.example.com/example.html')
```

Comment: `require 'open-uri'`. and then `file2 = open("http://....")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html).

```
require 'open-uri'

file2 = open('http://www.example.com/example.html')
```

Alternatively, you can pass in an `URI`

```
file2 = open(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/example.html'))
```